# Moving static IP Address on GCE without teardown

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm replacing a legacy GCE VM with an static external IP address with a new VM with that same address.

I want to validate that the new VM works before moving the external IP address to the new machine and tearing down the old one.

Is there a way to do this without downtime and tearing down the old VM?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on my own. This can be done through the following steps:

1. Going to the old VM and stopping it as an external IP cannot be released if it's in use.
2. Then go to `IP addresses` within that VPC network and select `Release Static Address`.
3. Reserve that IP address and assign to the new VM.

Note that these steps cannot be performed without downtime of the old VM as it will need to be stoped to release it's IP address.

Ideally this should be setup using a domain and a DNS A record instead.